# Writing running processes on text (OS X)

Tags: macos, process, prompt

I need to write running processes on txt file without copy-paste.

I tried `top> smthg.txt` but because top function shows continuous variables on terminal, it continuosly write all changes on txt. How can I just fetch instant `top` information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
top -l 1 -ncols 8 > smthg.txt
```